# Do characters know how to read/write languages or just speak them?

Tags: dnd-5e, languages

I noticed that the rules for language selection state

> Your race indicates the languages your character **can speak** by default, and your background might give you access to one or more additional languages of your choice.

But a Druid's Druidic class feature says

> You know Druidic, the secret language of druids. You can speak the language **and use it to leave hidden messages.**

And Speech of the woods:

> At 2nd level, you learn to speak, read, **and write** Sylvan.

It seems there's no evidence that a character is literate in the languages they know (except for class granted ones that explicitly state this is so). Am I missing something? Being too pedantic?

Comment: Were did you see that druids would learn Sylvan at 2nd level?

Comment: @alex It's from circle of the shepherd (Xanathar's Guide to Everything)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes, you can write the languages you can speak

On page 17 of the PHB, the ["Languages"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/races#Languages) section states (emphasis mine):

> #### Languages
>
> By virtue of your race, your character can speak, **read, and write** certain languages. Chapter 4 lists the most common languages of the D&D multiverse.

So by RAW you can read and write any language you know.

Comment: This is what happens when someone texts me a rule from somewhere in the internet and I don't double check the physical book >.>

Comment: @Rykara The text you quote is from page 123 of PHB, the person who texted you isn't wrong. It just appears in multiple places.

Comment: Deep Speech doesn't have a script and cannot be written.

Comment: In addition to Deep Speech (which, according to the [FR wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Speech), had no native script but was occasionally transcribed by the drow in Espruar (Elvish)), the [GGTR Languages table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/ggtr/welcome-to-ravnica#Languages) (p. 9) lists the Sphinx language with no written script.